# open earth map with irregular station measurement overlays

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, openmap

I would like to draw a map of current temperatures (or air pressures, etc.) from many weather stations, with the underlying map still recognizable.  the problem is easiest to think of as follows:

I have an array of spot measurements from irregularly spaced dots---think triples of GPS coordinates with one temperature value each.  my stations can be very close to or very far apart from one another, and a user may want to zoom in or out.   cold should be blue, warm should be red.  Ideally, I would like to just pass the array, the color range, and have the rest be taken care of.  I would prefer everything to be inside a web browser.  The user needs to be able to zoom in, zoom out, move around, and get back to his current location.

I do not even know how to think about this problem.  If a user has zoomed out enough, non-transparent dots could be so close as to obscure the terrain.  However, zooming in, it would be nice to recognize the dot that is the station itself.  This presumably requires some intelligence that realizes how many dots there are, e.g., relative to the density of the display?  not sure.

I believe google maps charges for many API calls, so I would prefer using an open map and/or open API that can use different underlying maps.  It does not have to be fancy.  I don't care about directions, etc.---just a map that is recognizable at most zoom settings, with landmark and street names, and my nice temperature station overlay coloring, so that a user can visualize where it is cold and where it is warm.

(Stations come online and offline, but I don't need to update this more than once an hour.  I can place the map measurements into a file that is URL web-accessible.)

is this an easy or a hard problem for the high-level web programmer?

/iaw

Answer (score 0):

after looking around for a long time, I think the best way to do this is with html5 openlayers nexrad.

alas, the docs seem to be a mess.  half the examples that I found did not seem to work.  it's pretty hit-or-miss.  similarly, the openlayers cookbook also seems to be outdated and has incorrect examples, but they did have a reasonably short example of such a nexrad map overlaid on the U.S., that one can further study.